# How to display dynamic default value in field of Strapi collection page?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, strapi

I want to display some read only URL in STRAPI collection page.
let's say I am at

`/admin/plugins/content-manager/collectionType/application::my-public-form.my-public-form/1`

now I have one field that need to display URL like this

`https://myurl/1`

is there is any way to get current url i.e. `/admin/plugins/content-manager/collectionType/application::my-public-form.my-public-form/1`

and in field I display `https://myurl/1`

Comment: Hey, did this work for you?

Answer (score 3):

This is going to be a lengthy answer, but let me try to simplify as much as possible.

##### Explanation:

To achieve this you need to simply create a field in the collection type and mark it as **non-editable** in the admin interface. This will make it a `read-only` property. Next, we need to override the `afterFindOne` from the [lifecycle hooks](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization/models.html#available-lifecycle-events) of the model so that when it fetches the entry from the db, we can pre-populate the url for that particular entry, so that it's displayed in the `read-only` field in the UI.

##### Implementation:

Let's assume we are creating a `collection-type` called **Student**, which some basic field like ***first_name***, ***last_name***, ***dob*** and ***student_url***. We are going to make the ***student_url*** field `read-only` in the following way:

1. Create the collection type `Student` as show in the screenshot.
   [image]
2. Visit the newly created `collection-type` in the [content-manager](http://localhost:1337/admin/content-manager/collectionType/api::student.student?page=1&pageSize=10&sort=first_name:ASC), click on `Create new entry` button, and then click on `Configure view` in the right hand panel.

[image]

3. Click on the small pencil icon which is besides the `student_url` field to open a popup, and then set the `Editable` property to `False` and click **Finish**.

[image]

4. At this point you're almost done, the only thing left to do is set the lifecycle hook to populate the `student_url` field when it's fetched from the database so that it's displayed correctly in our UI.
   Create a `lifecycles.js` file in your model folder.

```js
// src/api/student/content-types/student/lifecycles.js
module.exports = {
  afterFindOne(event) {
    const { result } = event;
    // You can easily change this line to `/admin/plugins/content-manager/collectionType/application::my-public-form.my-public-form/${result.id}` in your project. 
    if (result) result.student_url = `https://example.com/${result.id}`;
  },
};
```

And that's it. Now create an entry in the admin UI with the rest of editable fields and see entry being populated automatically with the `student_url`. Cheers!

[image]